# MIPS Concurrency

Tags: concurrency, mips

What is the difference between these two ways of storing a value in a global variable, in terms of concurrency?:

```
lis $4
.word 0x10008008
sw $3, 0($4)
```

vs

```
sw $3, 8($GP)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf

“lis $4” doesn't seems like a valid MIPS instruction